# Python virtualEnv and airflow bash operator

Tags: python, virtualenv, miniconda, airflow

I'm facing a weird issue.

I've deployed a complete Airflow setup but i've got an issue running python script using BashOperator

My dag looks like this :

```
 from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import pendulum


dag = DAG('ext_pipeline_import', description='Pipeline d''import des données extranet ', schedule_interval='00 04 * * *', start_date=pendulum.datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=20,tzinfo='Europe/Paris'),catchup=False)


t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t2',
    bash_command="customPython /data/airflow/dags/project/pyhton_src/myscript.py ",
    dag=dag
)



t2
```

And it keeps faillig on import on the modules in the customPython.

If I run `customPython /data/airflow/dags/project/pyhton_src/myscript.py` direct in terminal works like a charm. Any idea about what happend ? customPython  refers to a working python virtualenv

Comment: What do you mean by "deploying"? If you're having ImportErrors, you know that you have missing modules. Either you are using wrong python environment, or the module is not installed in the environment. Add  `print(sys.executable)` to the top of the script. That will say to you what python you are using. You can also check `sys.path` for the paths that are checked for modules.

Comment: It take the good one but my modules aren't included. Path are good but fail import

Comment: The exact same command send to the same terminal on the sama machine works good

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH was the correct issue.

I had to export the correct path before running my python.

Comment: @ airliquide how did you accomplish that within airflow? did you add it to the bash cmd?

Comment: Yes exactly ! Surcharging PYTHONPATH on each executor.